# ¿Cómo crear un query en spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Estoy tratando de crear un query en spring boot dentro del repository pero no me funciona no se que este haciendo mal

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mission_info")
public class MissionInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private Integer id_mission;
private Integer id_mission_img;
private String description;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public Integer getId_mission() {
    return id_mission;
}

public Integer getId_mission_img() {
    return id_mission_img;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setId_mission(Integer id_mission) {
    this.id_mission = id_mission;
}

public void setId_mission_img(Integer id_mission_img) {
    this.id_mission_img = id_mission_img;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

Repository

```
@Transactional
public interface MissionInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<MissionInfo,                   Serializable>{

@Query("SELECT description FROM MissionInfo")
public List<MissionInfo>findDescription();
}
```

service

```
@Transactional
public interface MissionInfoService {

List<MissionInfo> getDescription();
}
```

service impl

```
@Service
public class MissionInfoServiceImpl implements MissionInfoService{

@Autowired
private MissionInfoRepository MRepository;

@Override
public List<MissionInfo> getDescription() {
    return MRepository.findDescription();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Quizás es un poco tarde para responder, pero a alguien más le puede servir...*

Veo que en el repository tienes:

```
@Query("SELECT description FROM MissionInfo")
public List<MissionInfo>findDescription();
```

Donde `description` es un atributo de la entidad `MissionInfo`, ese atributo no debería estar en la query porque estas esperando una lista de tipo `MissionInfo`, intenta usando un alias, por ejemplo:

```
@Query("SELECT mi FROM MissionInfo mi")
public List<MissionInfo> findMissionInfo();
```

Si no necesitas todo el objeto `MissionInfo`, en la clase `ServiceImp` puedes recuperar solo la descripción y almacenarla en una lista de tipo String, por ejemplo:

Java8:

```
@Override
public List<String> getDescription() {
    return MRepository.findMissionInfo()
                      .stream()
                      .map(MissionInfo::getDescription)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Java7:

```
@Override
public List<String> getDescription() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MissionInfo missionInfo : MRepository.findMissionInfo()) {
        list.add(missionInfo.getDescription());
    }
    return list;
}
```

*Si esto no funciona, trata de agregar el error que te genera para poder encaminar la solución*

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear solo un metodo en tu repositorio y que Spring Data lo implemente automagicamente:

```
@Transactional
public interface MissionInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<MissionInfo,                   
Serializable>{

   public List<MissionInfo>findByDescription();
}
```

Spring Data va a implementar ese método al detectar las palabras find y By. Cualquier metodo del tipo findBy[parametro] puede ser implmementado automaticamente por Spring Data

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada podrías seguir el camino de la documentación, media ves tus consultas sean medianamente sencillas.

Doc: [https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference.)

Como segunda alternativa esta la anotación `@Query` que viene propia de `JPA`, con `@Query` puedes hacer consulta `JPQL o SQL Nativo`.

Al usar `SQL Nativo`, deberías usar el parámetro `nativeQuery` por ejemplo:
`@Query(value = "TU CONSULTA SQL NATIVA", nativeQuery = true)`